# Create list of valid ssn's

Tags: python-3.x

As an exercise (too old for homework) I would like to create a list of all valid SSN for a given country (e.g. Denmark CPR numbers). Being a python novice, I try the following:

```
from stdnum.dk import cpr
numbers = list(range(0000000001, 2000000000))
for number in numbers:
   if cpr.validate(str(number)):
      print(ssn)
```

Obviously I don't know enough about the python type system and conversion between numbers and strings:

```
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted
```

OK, let's start with a leading 1:

```
from stdnum.dk import cpr
numbers = list(range(1000000001, 2000000000))
for number in numbers:
   if cpr.validate(str(number)):
      print(ssn)
```

Which yields

```
$ uname -siopm
Linux x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
$ python3 ssn.py 
Killed
$
```

How should a go about creating the SSN list?

Comment: A list of numbers from 1000000001 to 2000000000 has ten billion numbers. If Python stores them in a 64-bit floating-point format, that requires 80 gigabytes of memory. Your system either does not have that much memory available for your process or is unable or unwilling to provide it to the process. You might be able to create a list in a file on disk, again requiring 80 gigabytes for the floating-point format or more for other formats, such as strings of digits or some arbitrary-length integer format. But to what purpose? That is a hugely inefficient use of storage.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for commenting, do note that I need only save the valid ssn's, not the entire range.